# At what speed did she throw the ball if it just made it to​ her friend

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, projectile-motion

A​ hot-air balloon left the ground rising at 9 feet per second. 14 seconds​ later, Victoria threw a ball straight up to her friend Colleen in the balloon.  At what speed did she throw the ball if it just made it to​ Colleen?

Comment: Victoria is at the ground?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the time when Victoria throws the ball be t =0 
So, equation for balloon will be

$$s = 126 + 9*t$$ and that for ball will be

$$ s_1 = u*t +1/2a*t^2$$
According to the question s = $s_1$ So,

$ 126 + (9-u) t = 16.1t^2$ --------(1)

Also according to question final velocity is zero so,

$t=-u/32.2$

Use this equation in (1) and solve the quadratic equation